# How to wait while jquery.contents() complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want dynamically set the height of an iframe when it will have been loaded. For this purpose I wrote this piece of JavaScript code, which in my dream can do it. But, in reality it can not.

Here is my code

```
 var iframes = (function () {
/* jQuery object of an iframe container */
var obj = null,

    /* Constructor function */
    initialize = function (obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
    }

initialize.prototype = {
  content: null,

  setContents: function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.obj.load(function () {
      self.content = self.obj.contents();
      if (callback) {callback();}
    });
  },

  /* Returns content of iframe
   */
  getContents: function () {
    return this.content;
  },

  setHeight: function () {
    var height = this.content.find('html').height();
    this.obj.css('height', height);
  },

  /*  Changes an element attribute in an iframe
   *  
   *  param selector: String id or class name to find an element
   *  param attrName: String an attribute's name to be changed
   *  param attrVal:  String value that should be applied to the attribute
   */
  changeAttr: function (selector, attrName, attrVal) {
    this.content.find(selector).attr(attrName, attrVal);
  },

  /*  Changes an element styles
   *  
   *  param selector: String id or class name to find an element
   *  param styles:   Object styles to be applied
   */
  changeStyle: function (selector, styles) {
    this.contents.find(selector).css(styles);
  },
};

return initialize;
 }());
```

I sent the setHeight method as a callback function, but looks like jQuery.contents() is asynchronous, but it has no any arguments, so I can't send a callback to the jQuery.contents()

Please, help me find the solution.

**EDITED**
I am not a Frontend developer, and I have poor experience with JavaScript, but I've tried to apply best practice. So I've used module pattern to create an Object.

After all I do

```
var ifrm = new iframes($('#ifrm'));
ifrm.setContents(setHeight);
```

It does not work(

Comment: `.contents()` is *not* asynchronous. `self` is a local variable to `setContents()`, it's not available in the `setHeight()` function.

Comment: @Juhana oops, I've edited this stupid mistake, but the code still does not work(

Comment: Most likely `this` doesn't point to what you think it points to. Why not pass `self` to `setHeight()` as a parameter?

Comment: I add more code, so you you can see full picture.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#iframeId').on("load",function()){
  var height = this.content.find('html').height();
  this.obj.css('height', height);
}
```

Comment: what is this? does it related to asked question :P